# Accumulative bar chart via VBA

Tags: vba, graph

I have code that generates a simple graph. Now, I want to change this to:

1) The X values must be A, B, C, D.

2) For each of the X values, i need an accumulated bar, accumulating three values - displayed in red, blue, amber. (It Means, I will have four bars, each bar containing a red, blue and amber part[accumulated bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39obb.png))

Please propose code? In example pic I still need to change X axis tags plus green colour should be amber.

BW Peter Bunde Hansen

```
Sub Example()
With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 300, 300).Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  .Name = "A B C D type errors"
  .XValues = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .Values = Array(1, 4, 9, 16)
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

What I want is a type xl3DColumnStacked graph , but it only accepts this:

```
Sub Example()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 300, 300).Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .Name = "A B C D type errors"
      .XValues = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      .Values = Array(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
      .Type = xl3DColumn
    End With
End Sub
```